# Swift 3 - Can not use array made Alamofire request

Tags: arrays, json, swift, uitableview

hoping that someone can help me! Working on this one for a while now. Basically  my problem is that I can not use the data in a UItableviewcontroller that is received by an Alamofire request. The request I want to put in a struct in the alamofire request. In the end I can not use the information what is put in the array. Looks like the array keeps empty outside the Function. for that I tried to make a closure, I receive the table in viewDidLoad request, but still can not use it outside that one.

I have a structure in a swift file called Section:

```
struct Mijnproducten {
    var productname : String!
    var productdesc : String!
    var expanded : Bool!

    init(productname: String, productdesc: String, expanded: Bool)
    {
        self.productname = productname
        self.productdesc = productdesc
        self.expanded = false
    }
 }
```

UitableviewController looks like this:

Array I made:

```
var mijnproducten01 = [Mijnproducten]()
```

Below the fund with alamofire request:

```
func GetUserProperty(completion: @escaping ([Mijnproducten]) -> Void) {

    Alamofire.request(URL_USER_PROPERTY, method: .post, encoding: JSONEncoding.default) .responseJSON(completionHandler: { response -> Void in
            //getting the json value from the server productid, tagid, status, productimage
            switch response.result {

            case .success(let value):
                let jsonArray = JSON(value)
                print(value)
                var Mijnproducten01 : [Mijnproducten] = []

                for (index, dict) in jsonArray {
                    let thisObject = Mijnproducten(productname: dict["productname"].string!, productdesc: dict["productdesc"].string!, expanded: false )
                    Mijnproducten01.append(thisObject) }

                completion(Mijnproducten01)

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                completion([])
            }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

In the viedDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      GetUserProperty(completion: { data in
       self.mijnproducten01 = data
        print("yess", self.mijnproducten01)})
        print("nooo",mijnproducten01)
}
```

There is printed information in the yesss print, but not in the nooo.

In the end the goal is to substract information from the array and use it in the tableCell and Header.

When I put this in the header function:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
       let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "expandableHeaderView") as! ExpandableHeaderView
        header.customInit(Productname: mijnproducten01[Mijnproducten].productname, Productdesc: mijnproducten01[Mijnproducten].productdesc, section: section, delegate: self)
        //print("print", mijnproducten01)
        return header
    }
```

I get an error in: mijnproducten01[Mijnproducten].productname.

I hope some one can help on the way!

Comment: are you gonna do expanding tableView?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want it is working at the moment. I followed a movie on Youtube to get what I want. But I misread something. I got everything working: replaced mijnproducten01[Mijnproducten].productname for mijnproducten01[count].productname, the variable that keeps track of the row in the array, Im a learner so it took  a while for me to see what the problem was. Thank you!!

Comment: Do you maybe know how I can retrieve a text label in the headerfield in the didSelectRowAt function? I can retrieve the row textfield, but I need the header/section textfield aswell.

Comment: just try indexPath.section

Comment: you will not get the `UILabel` but you can retrieve the value in that index from array that you given to section.

Comment: Thanks! I found a solution, maybe not the best way but it works. I added an extra UI label in the rows. That UI label gets assigned the value that is also used in the header. In the end I made the UILabel not visible. In this way I get with every row in a section the wright header description that I can get in didSelectRow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! I found a solution, maybe not the best way but it works. I added an extra UI label in the rows. That UI label gets assigned the value that is also used in the header. In the end I made the UILabel not visible. In this way I get with every row in a section the wright header description that I can get in didSelectRow!